# 'Tagging' an image in Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic, tagging, mechanicalturk

I am designing an experiment to test people's trust in certain images and was hoping to get an idea of what parts of the image they trusted/did not trust. I was thinking of creating something similar to Facebook tagging where a participant might click on a part of an image and a text box would open so they could type a comment. I have looked at various ways of doing this but have had no luck so far.

I am currently thinking the answer may lie in recording a click event by co-ordinates on the picture, having that click open a dynamic text box below/beside the image that they can type into, and then I would just have to match the click events with the text they enter when all data is exported.

Any thoughts on whether I am on the right track? Any help or ideas would be verrrry much appreciated - been pulling my hair out over this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you're on the right track. Check out these tutorials to see if they help. Basically they show how to create Human Intelligence Tasks (HITs) that ask Workers to draw a box around objects, then either type in a label, select a pre-defined label from a drop-down, or apply no label at all.

https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-annotating-images-with-bounding-boxes-using-amazon-mechanical-turk-42ab71e5068a#.e4danqmji

https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-retrieving-bounding-box-image-annotations-from-mturk-253b86cb7502#.h4ya5t58m

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! I've been searching for so long for a solution to this and this is perfect! You have no idea how grateful I am for your help thank you!